# How to modify/disable cloak on freenode?

Tags: irc, freenode

I recently discovered that I have a cloak on my freenode account.

If I try to disabled it with `/msg NickServ VHOST myusername OFF FORCE` I get this message:

```
Notice NickServ : You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

How can I modify/disable my cloak on freenode?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, cloak operations are made by FreeNode's staff. Simply join `#freenode` and ask them to remove it.